# How to get column value from reactive function

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I have *fluidRow*, where I have marked down box and added:

```
valueBoxOutput("income")
```

I also have another fluidRow, where I have marked down tabPanel:

```
tabPanel(
   "Table",
   dataTableOutput("table") #gives me Age, Income and Occupation.
```

I need to display average income depending on the user filtering in "table". Column names in database are: Age, Income and Job. Table itself is displayed just fine.

Here's what I have written so far, buy my "income" is empty and values are not changing.
Is this even possible to access one column from reactive function? If not, how can I access one column to calculate average income?

```
  selectedRows = reactive({
    input$table_rows_selected

  })
  
  output$income = renderValueBox({
    valueBox(
      width = 2,
      value = selectedRows()$Income %>% mean() ,
      subtitle = "Average income"
      )
  })
```

Comment: Can you show us what your code for the `table_rows_selected` input looks like please? Knowing what value this produces will help others know how it can be used to produce a dynamic mean.

Comment: Sure. I used renderRataTable to get the table:

output$table = renderDataTable({
    dataframe %>% 
      select(Age, Income, Occupation) %>% 
      datatable(options = list(paginate = F), filter = "top", colnames = c("Age"= "Age", "Income" = "Income", "Job Title" = "Occupation")) 
  })

Comment: Right, got you. Being able to use `table_rows_selected` is a non-obvious feature of `datatable` outputs, so this could possibly be clarified in your question. This should be enough to go on though.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using `DT::datatable()` to get `input$table_rows_selected`. The documentation for `DT::datatable()` states the following:

> The "indices"' format of selected and selectable: when target is 'row' or 'column', it should be a plain numeric vector; when target is 'row+column', it should be a list, specifying rows and cols respectively, e.g., list(rows = 1, cols = 2); when target is 'cell', it should be a 2-col matrix, where the two values of each row stand for the row and column index.

This could be clearer, but the message is that if you're only selecting *rows*, then `input$table_rows_selected` will give a numeric vector of the indices of the selected rows. So you need to extract these rows and then compute the mean of the relevant column, which in this case is `Income`. You can do this easily using `dplyr`:

```
output$income = renderValueBox({

  dynamic_mean <- my_data %>%
    slice(input$table_rows_selected) %>%
    pull(Income) %>%
    mean()

  valueBox(
    width = 2,
    value = dynamic_mean,
    subtitle = "Average income"
  )
})
```